# How to add a condition to a match in case ... of

Tags: elm

In functional languages, one can add a condition to a branch of a pattern matching: for example, in OCaml:

```ml
let value = match something with
| OneThing -> "1"
| Another when condition -> "2"
| _ -> "3"
```

How to do this in elm? I tried `when` and `if`, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elm does not have conditionals within pattern matching, probably because the language designers tend to prefer to keep syntax small and simple.

The best you can do is something like this:

```
let
    value =
        case something of
            OneThing ->
                "1"

            Another ->
                if condition then
                    "2"
                else
                    ...

            _ ->
                "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to using an `if` within the `case` branch, you might want to instead match against a tuple containing the condition, which would look like this:

```
let
    value =
        case ( something, condition ) of
            ( OneThing, _ ) ->
                "1"

            ( Another, True ) ->
                "2"

            _ ->
                "3"
```

Comment: This solution is good only when there is one condition in the branches. If you want two different conditions, that is no more possible.

Comment: @Boiethios, it certainly gets hairier if you're introducing multiple conditions, and I would recommend switching to the `if`/`else` in that case.  However, I don't think there's anything impossible about having two different conditions, you just add another element to the tuple you're matching on.  See https://ellie-app.com/mkqNvychwa1/0, let me know if I'm missing your meaning

Comment: You are right, I did not think about it. However, as you say, this method will quickly clutter the code while adding conditions. In my learning project I switched to `if` ... `else`. This choice from elm team do *not* keep the language "simple" IMO because it forces to write less readable code (example: https://gitlab.com/snippets/1679916#L73 ) Maybe I will post about this in their repository.

Comment: @bdukes Welcome in the 100k club!